# Draw moving polygons with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have many polygons whose vertices moves every time step of a simulation, and after all the new polygons form are calculated they have to be plotted to a matplotlib fig.

When the code was static, i used path and patches to draw the polygons, like

```
for polygon in P:
    path = Path(polygon)
    patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=1)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
```

But of course doing this while the polygons are updated causes to draw over the last polygon, and it is not a clean update. The format of the polygon is a list with numpy arrays, each one is a vertex of the polygon, like `[[0.1223, 0.234], [0.123,0.4323], [0.2133, 0.5433]]`

I do can draw the vertices without the lines as `points = ax.plot(vertices[:,0], vertices[:,1], '.')[0]` and update them by using `points.set_data(...)`, then drawing the canvas. I am not using FuncAnimation because the examples I saw updates the data thanks to FuncAnimation itself; in my case, the data is generate through iterations, at the end of each iteration, changes in polygons must be plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the example below. It will draw a box moving in a circle. It should be easy to adapt to your application.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

import numpy as np
import math
import time

verts = np.array([[0.,0.],[0.,1.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,0.]])

codes = [Path.MOVETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.LINETO,
         Path.CLOSEPOLY,
         ]

path = Path(verts, codes)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
plt.show(block=False)
i=0.0
while i<100:
#for i in range(100):
    ax.clear()
    x=math.sin(i)
    y=math.cos(i)

    print x, y

    verts2=np.copy(verts)
    for j in range(len(verts)):
        verts2[j]=verts[j]+np.array([x,y])
    path = Path(verts2, codes)
    patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='orange', lw=2)
    ax.add_patch(patch)
    plt.draw()
    i+=0.1
```

Comment: Indeed, the main changes is that for many polygons I have to iterate over the list that contains them, then build each patch and finally draw everything. The key, I think, is the ax.clear(), because in older codes I tried efectively I couldn't "clear the screen buffer" or clean the last plot. Thanks!